# Check a list to see if its values match another list

Tags: python, list

I have a game of monopoly that I am creating, in this, I have one list called properties that contains all property names:

```
property = ["Go", "Mediterranean Ave", "Community Chest", "Baltic Ave", "Income Tax", "Reading Railroad",
        "Oriental Ave", "Chance", "Vermont Ave", "Connecticut Ave", "jail/Just Visiting", "St. Charles Place",
        "Electric Company", "States Ave", "Virginia Ave", "Pennsylvania Railroad", "St. James Place",
        "Community Chest", "Tennessee Ave", "New York Ave", "Free Parking", "Kentucky Ave", "Chance",
        "Indiana Ave", "Illinois Ave", "B. & O. Railroad", "Atlantic Ave", "Ventnor Ave", "Water Works",
        "Marvin Gardens", "Go to Jail", "Pacific Ave", "North Carolina Ave", "Community Chest",
        "Pennsylvania Ave", "Short Line Railroad", "Chance", "Park Place", "Luxury Tax", "Boardwalk"]
```

I also have a colour list which marks the properties colours:

```
propertyColor = [
"None", "Brown", "None", "Brown", "None", "None", "Navy", "None", "Navy", "Navy", "None", "Pink", "None", "Pink", "Pink", "None", "Orange", 
"None", "Orange", "Orange", "None", "Red", "None", "Red", "Red", "None", "Yellow", "Yellow", "None", "Yellow", "None", "Green", "Green", "None",
"Green", "None", "None", "Blue", "None", "Blue"
```

]

And each player has a dictionary tied to their name

```
        {
         "playerName": name,
         "money": settings[4],
         "properties": ["Mediterranean Ave", "Baltic Ave"],
         "railroads": [],
         "inJail":   False,
         "PlayerLocation": 0
         }
```

I would like to make it so that if the user wants to build an apartment on a property the program would check whether the user had all three of the properties in the same colour group it will follow through with the next command, how would this be done.

Comment: what did you try already? It is always better to have a starting point.

Comment: How are `property` and `propertyColor` linked? How do you know all properties are in the same colour group?

Comment: You need to link properties to their color groups.  For instance, extend `property` to be a dict, in which the value is the key's color.  You may also want a reverse dict that gives the 2-4 properties in each group (you might want the 4 RRs).

Comment: Be careful, in traditional monopoly, some property groups only have 2 properties in the group, rather than 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code

```
user_properties = ["Mediterranean Ave", "Baltic Ave"]
from collections import Counter
repeat = [propertyColor[property.index(x)] for x in user_properties]
repeat_dict = Counter(repeat)
```

Output

```
Counter({'Brown': 2})
```

Then check if there is any color having 3 counts.

```
{v: k for k, v in repeat_dict.items()}
{2: 'Brown'}
```